# Basic concept of Qt model/view and QTableView

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

I want to create a software that will browse some database tables and users will be able to edit these tables.  Following my reading of this [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html), I tought that model/view was a good approach for what I need.  Look at the following mockup :
[image]

Knowing this, I have questions to be sure that I understand the concept.  Please, tell my if I am in the good direction :

1. I guess I need to create a model class for each of my tables?
   (subclassing QAbstractModel).  It will look like this :

   ```
   class citiesTableModel : public QAbstractItemModel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    }
   ```
2. citiesTableModel constructor will fetch data from the table
   in the database?

   ```
   QAbstractItemModel *model = new citiesTableModel(); //model will contain 2 rows, New York and Seattle
   ```
3. Do I need to subclass QTableView for every different model?

   ```
   class citiesTableView : public QTableView{}
   ```
4. Finnaly, I guess that view.setData and view.setModel need to be
   reimplemented?  setModel will loop over each model rows to build the
   QTableView, and setData will do proper query to add new data in the
   model?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`QSqlTableModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html) for this.

As the doc says, it can be used quite easy:

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
model->setTable("employee");
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();
model->setHeaderData(0, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Name"));
model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("Salary"));

QTableView *view = new QTableView;
view->setModel(model);
view->hideColumn(0); // don't show the ID
view->show();
```

> I guess I need to create a model class for each of my tables?

Yes, one model represents one sql table.

> citiesTableModel constructor will fetch data from the table in the database?

`QSqlTableModel` will do it for you:

```
QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(parentObject, database);
model->setTable("employee");
model->select();
```

> Do I need to subclass QTableView for every different model?

No, you don't. A single `QTableview` can display any model you set using `setModel`.

> Finnaly, I guess that view.setData and view.setModel need to be
>   reimplemented? setModel will loop over each model rows to build the
>   QTableView, and setData will do proper query to add new data in the
>   model?

Depending on the edit strategy you set using `setEditStrategy`, the changes will be commited as your are editing table cells, or after you submit them using `submitAll`.

Also, you may want to take a look at the [`QDataWidgetMapper`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatawidgetmapper.html). It can map your model data to different widgets and track the changes you are doing editing those widgets.

Comment: Thx for your answer.  It actually looks a little bit easier than I tought.  Question : Our database is postgreSQL.  Do you know if QSqlTableModel works with this database?  Also, for edit strategy, It won't actually be possible to modify through tableview itself, only with the form (bellow tableview).  Does it make things even more easier?    Finnaly, are you sure I don't need to subclass QTableView?  If I want to convert boolean to checkbox? Thx

Comment: Yes, it can work with any database, if you have an appropriate qt sql plugin. Yes, it is possible to edit data through a table. To display boolean values as checkboxes, you should use [delegate classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html#delegate-classes).

Comment: Thx again for your answer.  Something that I was not clear enough.  Actually, this is a design decision. What we want : The user will NOT be able to edit the table view itself.  User will have to first select a row and the form will be filled accordingly, and user will modify the form.

Comment: Is `submitAll` supposed to be a member of `QTableView` because I can't find it?

Comment: `bool QSqlTableModel::submitAll ()   [slot]`

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have different options:

Either you database is a SQL database. You can use a subclass [QSqlTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html).
Otherwise if you want to create your model from scratch you do your own model but I don't see the point. You also have [QTableModel](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-tablemodel.html) with an example.

You don't need to create a model for each of your table, because it is always a tablemodel. The model mostly defines how you can add and remove rows with your specific data.

Concerning the view, you will have to inherit QTableView to add a custom behavior for you rows and cols, such as drag events for instance.

The only element of customization that you need is a delegate for your view or just for a column. It will basically convert a boolean value in your model into a checkbox.

I suggest you look at [SpinBox delegate](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/itemviews-spinboxdelegate.html) for more precision.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

In the case of a PostgreSQL you can add it in a QsqlDatabase:

```
 QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
 db.setHostName("acidalia");
 db.setDatabaseName("customdb");
 db.setUserName("mojito");
 db.setPassword("J0a1m8");
 bool ok = db.open();
```

Then pass the db to the QSqlTableModel. If you need more relational operation, such as fetching fields from a foreign key, you can use:

```
QSqlRelationalTableModel
QSqlRelationalDelegate
```